# The order of multiplications

Tags: c++, operator-keyword, operator-precedence

What's the order C++ does in chained multiplication ?

```
int a, b, c, d;
// set values
int m = a*b*c*d;
```

Comment: Didn't they mention at school that multiplication is commutative?

Comment: @Jon The relevant property is associativity, not commutativity. And school arithmetic is not immediately applicable here: `int` types are not the integers we use in mathematics, all operations are modulo 2^N. It just so happens that this doesn't damage the associativity for `unsigned` types, but signed integer overflow is undefined behavior and *float* multiplication isn't associative (neither is addition).

Comment: @jon i think your comment is meaningless, letting you know that for  matrixes a*b != b*a !! so this is the actual reason I asked a question

Comment: @arammis Matrix multiplication is associative though.

Comment: @arammis: Actually no, they give the same result, but anyway. You could make the context more clear if you did anything other than labelling those as `int` -- for example, saying "assume that a, b, c are user-defined types that overload the multiplication operator".

Comment: @Jon what gives same result ??? for integers yes it is the same, but not for maxtrixes, and my question is c++ language specific not school OKAY?

Comment: @delnan I'm taking about the order not the associativity or commutativity

Comment: @arammis Yes, you're talking about the order of parentheses. But if the operation is associative, the order does not matter (i.e., `a * (b * c)` is the same as `(a * b) * c`), therefore matrices are a bad example for why this order matters.

Comment: @delnan yea I know martices mult is assosiative, but I thought compiler may do b*a instead of a*b ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of commutative mathematical operations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49506802/608639), [C/C++ Math Order of Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11296854/608639), [What are the rules governing C++ single and double precision mixed calculations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4239770/608639), [Order of operations to maximize precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45524072/608639), etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

operator `*` has [left to right](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) associativity:

```
int m = ((a * b) * c) * d;
```

While in math it doesn't matter (multiplication is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property)), in case of both C and C++ we may have or not have overflow depending on the order.

```
0 * INT_MAX * INT_MAX // 0
INT_MAX * INT_MAX * 0 // overflow
```

And things are getting even more complex if we consider floating point types or operator overloading. See comments of **@delnan** and **@melpomene**.

Comment: But it does not matter

Comment: @EdHeal What if you have an overloaded `operator*`? Then it would matter.

Comment: Yes - but the question at hand is to do with ints. Anyway should it not behave the same?!

Comment: @EdHeal No, the question is about `*` in general. The example just happens to use `int`. And even with `int` it matters because of overflow: `0 * INT_MAX * INT_MAX`. If `INT_MAX * INT_MAX` is done first, it overflows, causing undefined behavior; but if `0 * INT_MAX` is done first, the result is simply 0.

Comment: Am I reading a different question - or are you reading something more into the question

Comment: @melpomene Thanks! I added it to the answer, hopefully you do not mind. (I was about to make the same remark about overflow, but was checking the standard, and found that you did it already.)

Comment: @EdHeal: You seem to be reading a different question; this one is quite clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the order is from left to right.

```
int m = a * b * c * d;
```

If you are more interested in the topic of evaluation order or operator precedence, then you might be surprised how some ++ operations behave, even differently with the version of C.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 2):

The order is from left to right in this case
where

```
int m=a*b*c*d;
```

Here, first (a*b) is computed then the result is multiplied by c and then d as shown using parentheses:

```
int m=(((a*b)*c)*d);
```

Answer (score 2):

The order is nominally left to right.  But the optimizers in C++ compilers I've used feel free to change that order for data types they think they understand.  If you overload operator* and the optimizer can't see through your overload, then it can't change the order.  But when you multiply a sequence of things (variables, constants, function results, etc.) whose type is double, the optimizer might use the associative and commutative property of real number multiplication as if it were true in float or double multiplication.  That can lead to some surprises when least significant bits matter to you.

So far as I understand, the standard allows that optimization, but I am far from a "language lawyer" so my best guess on the standard is not a pronouncement to be trusted (as compared with my experience on what compilers actually do).

Comment: If the optimizer rearranges evaluation order of floating point operators, it is violating the standard so you should report it as a bug. "Operators can be regrouped according to the usual mathematical rules only where the operators really are associative or commutative." (1.9/p.9).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any special "order" it multiplies as shown, left to right.

```
int m = a * b * c * d;
```

The order of operations comes into affect when using addition/ subtraction with dividing/ multiplying. Otherwise it is always left to right. Regardless, with the example, the solution would be the same no matter which order they were in.

Comment: If "it multiplies as shown, left to right", then that is an order.

Comment: _"Regardless, with the example, the solution would be the same no matter which order they were in"_ Hmm, what about overflow, which may happen or not depending on the order?